# Cross entropy of product of sequence for sequence tagging

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, cross-entropy

So I'm training a charterer level NN to do sequence tagging, simple NER (**P**erson, **O**bject, ...) 
Say I have a training example like (and perfect knowledge of how to tokenize the text )

```
President Donald Trump eats food

PPPPPPPPP PPPPPP PPPPP      OOOO
```

When I train the model with a cross entropy loss I'm training it to make predictions at the charterer level, which I actually don't care about.

Since at training time I can tokenize, would it make sense to calculate the gradient based on the cross entropy of the product of the probabilities of each charterers in the  token and the class I the token has.

So say "President Donald Trump" is a single token (for my tokenizer).
Instead of making a prediction at each charechter and taking a cross entropy for each charterer - I take the prediction (the probabilties) at each charterer, take their product and take the cross entropy of that product ?